# Extract data from S/4HANA Using TCodes

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, s4hana

I have a requirement that I have multiple S/4HANA Tcodes which are generating reports from underlying tables present in S/4HANA on premise. I want to export the data generated by Tcodes to my GCP bucket or to BigQuery data warehouse using Python.

Any help will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: There is dedicated page on titled as SAP on google cloud which also has information on SAP connector https://cloud.google.com/solutions/sap/docs/bq-connector/latest/install-config-off-gc as well as data fusion plug-in for SAP here https://cloud.google.com/solutions/sap/docs/cdf-plugin-for-sap . hope this helps

Comment: I guess you are talking about SAP software based on ABAP, but there are lots of such software, so which one is it? Also, there are thousands of "Transaction Codes" which use ABAP, SQL, other programming languages to output data, and render result in many ways, so it's impossible to answer your question precisely.

Comment: I guess you mean S/4HANA. Revert back if it's incorrect and indicate the actual SAP software name.